# Using JavaScript I would like to be able to parse the value out of a Source string parameter

Tags: javascript, parsing, url

I would like to extract a parameter out of a parameter.

"http://somewhere.html?ID=146+Source=http://elsewhere.html?ParentID=80"

It seems as if it should be pretty straight forward although perhaps a bit uncommon.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you read [ask] ? And please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What am I to try? The second '?' is nested. Just wondering how do I do a split on that?

Comment: That's an invalid URL. The part after "Source=" should be percent encoded.